# How can I add helper text by default to my Rails migrations via generators?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

We had this idea at work to automagically add some best practices for migrations as a comment block in Rails migrations. I figured it would be as easy as extending a template or generator, but I can't seem to find where we'd stick this.

Has anyone done this? How would you go about it on Rails 4.2?